# Programmatically access/add/change ringtones of contacts

Tags: iphone

Using the iPhone SDK is there a way to programmatically access (read/write) the ring tone that is assigned to a contact in the Address Book?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there aren't any official API that allows you to do that. You should submit a feature request to Apple if you feel this should be included. https://bugreport.apple.com