# iPhone Settings programmatically

Tags: iphone, settings

can i change the iPhone settings programmatically?
For example.. I want to change my ringtone through my application ??
Is it possible or what ??

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible unless jail broken as said in the second link...

[Programmatically access/add/change ringtones of contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283099/programmatically-access-add-change-ringtones-of-contacts)

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/13138-change-ringtone-programmatically.html

Comment: how can in a jailbroken phone ? any idea ??

Comment: You could SSH into your jailbroken iphone and find the files.  I don't know where it would be in the hierarchy in the phone though.