# Xcode: Accessing and Setting Custom Ringtones for Contacts

Tags: ios, xcode, contacts, ringtone

**Xcode and iOS App**

Is there any solution that will programmatically allow me to set custom ringtones for people on my contact list for an iOS device? I've came across a thread that says it's not possible. I'm just trying to verify if this is true or not?

If it **not** true, how to do this?

Comment: It's duplicate I think. You can find your answer here
No, still Apple not allowing to set ringtone for contact.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283099/programmatically-access-add-change-ringtones-of-contacts?rq=1

Comment: @MiteshPrajapati Thanks for your response, I was afraid of that though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically access/add/change ringtones of contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283099/programmatically-access-add-change-ringtones-of-contacts)